# Conditions where Euler's method over-estimates or under-estimates

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a rule that characterizes when Euler's method over-estimates or under-estimates?

For example, "if $f(x)$ is increasing, then Euler's method underestimates," or something similar?

Comment: Is $f$ a solution, or the right-hand side of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Euler's method will overestimate when the second derivative of $f$ is negative. This comes from the Taylor's series of the function:  $$f(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x)+\frac 12(x-x_0)^2f''(x) + \dots$$  Euler's method accounts for the $f'$ term but no more.  This is not absolute. For a given step size, the third derivative could be huge and swamp the effect of the second.  Higher order methods account for more terms of the Taylor series.

Comment: I think your answer supposes that $f(x)$ is the solution. My reading of the question was that $f(x)$ is the right hand side, i.e., the equation is $\dot x=f(x)$. If this is the case, the increasing/decreasing behavior of $f$ will be the first factor.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday:  you are correct that I took $f(x)$ as the solution of the differential equation. I agree that the question is not clear.  Thanks. The question is old enough that the odds of an answer from OP are low.

Comment: This is a late comment, but I am not sure what "generally speaking" mean in your answer. The first step of Euler method will indeed be an overestimate if the solution curve is concave down, but the second step can jump below the curve, so the second step can be an underestimate even when the second derivative of the particular solution is negative. Did you mean that Euler method surely gives an overestimate if all solution curves has negative second derivative everywhere?

Comment: @FerencBeleznay:  I explained that at the end.  The third or later derivatives can be positive and large enough to make the Euler method an underestimate.  If the step is small they need to be quite large.  The functions we usually use do not have this behavior.

Comment: I do not mean to seem picky, but for the differential equation $y'=-3x^2-2x-3y$ the particular solution for $y(0)=0$ is $y=-x^2$. This has $0$ higher derivatives, yet Euler's method with step size $1$ gives the points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(2,-5)$, which is an underestimate of the true value $-4$.